# Saving then accessing entity from managedObjectContext in CoreData occasionally crashes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm struggling to debug a hard-to-reproduce-locally crash in my app. The crash reports show the exception type is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)` with `objc_msgSend` at the top of the crashed thread, perhaps suggesting ***"The process may have attempted to message a deallocated object"*** (as per Apple's documents).

I have not been able to recreate the crash or find any zombies using the `Zombies instrument,` despite using an older device and the same simulated device causing the most crashes.

From the trace I'm pretty sure I've been able to work out where the crash is occurring, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My app is basically a group database. The app takes a username and password, sending them to a server to check if the person can be logged in. If valid, the app downloads the data on all the people in the group, then finds the logged in person from the downloaded data based on their username.

Because of the way the server code is set up, the username must be present in the downloaded data (if it all downloads correctly), yet my code occasionally fails to find them, and (from the crash logs) also occasionally this attempted finding of the person causes a crash.

```swift
coreDataStack.storeContainer.performBackgroundTask() { context in
     OverallNetworkCalls.deleteAllLoadPeople(moContext: context) { result in
      self.coreDataStack.saveNewContext(context: context)
      if result == .success {
           let person = AdministrativeHelperFunctions.returnCurrentUserFromUserName(moContext: context)
           if let person = person {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                 }
                 UserDefaults.standard.set(person.objectID.uriRepresentation(), forKey: udl.CurrentUserMOID.rawValue)
           } else {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                   self.loadingLabel.text = "Data was downloaded but your username isn't there. Try deleting and reloading the app, or contact admin."
           }
       }
  }

func saveNewContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    context.perform {
        guard context.hasChanges else { return }
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            //logs the issue locally 
        }
    }
}

func returnCurrentUserFromUserName(moContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Person? {
    let userName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username")
    if let userName = userName {
         //Create predicate, arrayForResults etc
         do {
              userNameMatchesArray = try moContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
         } catch {
             //logs the issue locally
         }

         if userNameMatchesArray.count == 1 {
              return userNameMatchesArray[0]
         } else {
              return nil
         }
     } else {
        return nil
     }
}
```

My suspicion is that the `returnCurrentUserFromUserName` function is returning the user before the `saveNewContext` function has completed its task and that this is contributing to the issue, though given the same managedObjectContext is saving then retrieving the person I had originally assumed this wasn't a problem. I'm also not sure that using "context.perform" in the `saveNewContext` function is necessary/wise/useful; I'd value feedback on this too if anyone knows best practice inside a performBackgroundTask block.

A non-reproduceable bug is always the most frustrating to fix, and because of this anything I try to fix it won't be shown until I send it to my beta testers and get crashlogs back (or not!).

Thanks in advance for reviewing this problem.

Comment: In the case of the fetch happening before the save: You could perform the save and the fetch inside a `context.performAndWait {` block. This would ensure that one waits for the other to finish

Comment: Thanks Igor, you're right that would ensure it finished first, but is that likely to be the problem? Frustratingly, because I can't reproduce the issue I can't just try it and see if it works!

Comment: If there a reason you place the call to `.save` in the `context.perform{}` closure? I suspect this is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks andrewbuilder; I was reading as much as I could about multithreading in an attempt to understand it better, and one of the things was making sure everything for a particular MOC was performed inside a `perform` or `performAndWait` closure. I ended up scatter-gunning the closures throughout without really understanding it! I think you're right that it's unnecessary, and assume that the `performBackgroundTask` block doubles as a `context.perform{}` closure - is this an accurate assumption do you know?

Comment: I recommend you review your assumptions... 1. I’d strongly discourage use of scatter gun approach in any programming - practice restraint, write only code that is absolutely necessary to achieve an outcome; 2. Don’t assume any code “doubles” in programming - practice precision, especially with asynchronous tasks and tasks executed on more than one thread, using breakpoints and `print()` to terminal, step through each task line by line to understand exactly how your code executes.

Comment: Also I suggest you re-read the first paragraph of your own question... you answer it yourself. Somewhere, your code is attempting to access an object that is no longer in memory. So which object? Where does it drop out - which line? Answer these questions and you’ll be a lot closer to debugging your code. In my experience (mostly with `PHPhoto` framework), this type of error occurs when one asynchronous task completes and deallocates its objects in the heap, while another asynchronous task continues, which relies on one of those objects to function and/or complete.